# Re-using Joomla module positions not setting Bootstrap Column width correctly

Tags: joomla-3.x, php, module

I want to use 1 module position (showcase) but have duplicate modules set the bootstrap column width based on the amount of modules assigned to that position.

I have written the following code:

```
<div class="row">
    <?php if($this->countModules('showcase')) : ?>
        <div class="col-md-<?php echo (12/$this->countModules('showcase'));?>">
            <jdoc:include type="modules" name="showcase" />
        </div>
    <?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

but this is outputting the following html:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="block">
            <h2 class="header">Show Case 1</h1>
            <div class="custom">
                <p>This is a test</p>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="custom">
            <h2 class="header">Show Case 2</h1>
            <p>This is a test</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

rather than (how I want it to look):

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="block">
            <h2 class="header">Show Case 1</h1>
            <div class="custom">
                <p>This is a test</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6">
        <div class="block">
            <h2 class="header">Show Case 2</h1>
            <div class="custom">
                <p>This is a test</p>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reason being is that you've got your `jdoc:include` inside the following wrapper:

```
<div class="col-md-<?php echo (12/$this->countModules('showcase'));?>">
```

So all the modules assigned to this position will be displayed within this wrapper.

---

Have a look at the following file:

> templates/YOUR_TEMPLATE/ html/modules.php

In here you'll see the variables and HTML markup that will be wrapped around your module. Your best bet will be to do the following:

**index.php:**

```
<?php if ($this->countModules('showcase')) : ?>
    <div class="row">
        <jdoc:include type="modules" name="showcase" style="mystyle" />
    </div>
<?php endif; ?>
```

Then add a new `mocChrome` to the file mentioned above:

```
function modChrome_mystyle($module, &$params, &$attribs)
{
    $moduleTag     = $params->get('module_tag', 'div');
    $bootstrapSize = (int) $params->get('bootstrap_size', 0);
    $moduleClass   = $bootstrapSize != 0 ? ' col-md-' . $bootstrapSize : ' col-md-12';
    $headerTag     = htmlspecialchars($params->get('header_tag', 'h3'), ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');
    $headerClass   = htmlspecialchars($params->get('header_class', 'page-header'), ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8');

    if ($module->content)
    {
        echo '<' . $moduleTag . ' class="' . htmlspecialchars($params->get('moduleclass_sfx'), ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8') . $moduleClass . '">';

            if ($module->showtitle)
            {
                echo '<' . $headerTag . ' class="' . $headerClass . '">' . $module->title . '</' . $headerTag . '>';
            }

            echo $module->content;
        echo '</' . $moduleTag . '>';
    }
}
```

Note I have used `style="mystyle"` (default) in the index.php and the name of the modChrome function is `modChrome_mystyle`.

You'll also see that the bootstrap size will default to `12` is not specified.

Once you've done all this, ensure that you assign this style to the modules in this position.

Hope this helps

Comment: You're welcome. Glad it helped.